# How do I make the VideoView play the video with the Drive link?

Tags: android, url, networking, video

So I am trying to make a VideoView play a video with a link from Drive. I made the Network security configuration and the video can't be played still ("Your video can't be played.") I realized that the problem is not the code, but the link. I tried links from already made players and some work some not. I only want to make the video work. With either the drive link or another method. I am going to show you what I did. I would appreciate it if someone will help me .

The code:

```
 VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.SY);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CRJ8tL-DyjD0Nwd7ezkboGm6570zMf4C/view?usp=sharing");
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

    MediaController mc = new MyMediaController(videoView.getContext());
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);

    videoView.start();

    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> onBackPressed());
```

The network xml:

```
<network-security-config>
<domain-config>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">diligent_app.com</domain>
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system"/>
    </trust-anchors>
</domain-config>
```

```
Manifest:
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network"
```

What I got as an error

```
2021-08-30 14:53:35.338 4582-7140/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{4c93299 
u0 com.example.diligent/com.diligent_app.diligent.yoga.Yoga} 
destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false 
win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8 
caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5227 
com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5208 
com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:5267 
com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:5894 
com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.activityStopped:2584 
android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub.onTransact:2215 
android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal:1190 
2021-08-30 14:53:35.605 4302-16264/? E/GenericSource: text/html from 
getMIMEType()
2021-08-30 14:53:35.605 12855-15380/com.example.diligent 
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -1015)
2021-08-30 14:53:35.606 12855-12855/com.example.diligent E/MediaPlayer: 
Error (1,-1015)
2021-08-30 14:53:37.695 4582-6879/? E/TaskPersister: File error 
accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2021-08-30 14:53:42.774 4582-4618/? E/BatteryStatsService: Unable to load 
Power Hal or power.stats HAL
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link with `sharing` in its URL will just take you to a web page (not video data).

For downloading the video data into your player, try as:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1CRJ8tL-DyjD0Nwd7ezkboGm6570zMf4C");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. You saved me.